# Is there a way to add $filter in the state function of stateprovider in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am new to angular js and I am trying to add the custom filter to alter the dynamic url inside a state provider.
can't get it to work though,
can anyone let me know where am i going wrong or is the approach correct

I have attached the code for my state provider where I have tried to add the filter

```
  .state('app.gotoPropertyDetails', {
  url: 'property-details/:property_id/(:seo_details | camelCaseToHyphens)',
  templateUrl: 'views/propertyDetails.html',
  controller: 'propertyDetailsCtrl',
  params: {property_id: null,seo_details:null}
})
```

Comment: Manipulation of a state parameter should be done in the controller, not in the state definition.

Comment: @georgeawg I am trying to call this state from multiple controllers and which is why i was trying to do it here,so that it could be applicable across all controllers. Thanks for your reply

Comment: Functions common to multiple controllers should be re-factored into a service.

Comment: Okay @georgeawg, the problem is I was looking for something where unlike service I actually don't have to inject it into all my controllers, but something that happens on the fly, but your approach sounds better to be implemented,